# How to verify if the user and password part is readable by intermediary servers when accessing a url

Tags: http, authentication, url, curl, python-requests

If I want to use URL authentication of the form:

`http://user:password@domain.tld`

Is it guaranteed that the user and password are not seen by any servers between me and the requests's destination?
I'd like to know how to check this myself.

This is what I tried so far:
I've set a netcat server to listen on port 9090 and sent request with both python's request library and curl to check out what is received by a server.

Python request:

```
requests.get("http://foo:bar@localhost:9090")
```

What nc shows me:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9090
User-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==
```

curl request:

```
curl 'foo:bar@localhost:9090'
```

nc:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9090
Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
```

I noticed that the credentials are converted into an `Authorization` header. Netcat shows me the headers and body of the request but not what happens until it reaches it.

Is it possible for intermediate servers to find out my credentials?

Answer (score 1):

***Is it possible for intermediate servers to find out my credentials?***

Yes, if you are communicating on an unencrypted channel (like http protocol). The Authorization header is nothing but Base64 encoding of username and password concatenated. You can try decode "Zm9vOmJhcg==" as mentioned in the question here - https://codebeautify.org/base64-decode. However if you are communicating on a secure channel (like https), the intermediate servers cannot see it.

Comment: I think he might be asking what happens to the URL, on the DNS level, or whatever other levels are involved. I personally also know how the HTTP headers and body gets transmitted, but don't know who gets to see the URL.